# How can I display input box for individual parameter for POST/PUT request while using GenericView with django-rest-swagger

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui, django-rest-swagger

I'm using `Django REST Framework` (3.9.4) and `django-rest-swagger` (2.2)

In `view.py` I'm using `generic class-based views` such as `generics.ListCreateAPIView` and `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`

In swagger page it's enlisting correctly all API with their corresponding method calls.

When It's an API call for `PUT`, for `{id}` it's asking to provide input in an input box. But for request-body it's asking to provide the whole Json as an input.

**I want to change it such a way that for all request-body parameters, each of them will come as an individual input-box similar to id field of header ( kind of we see in Browsable API display)**

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: `SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'JSON_EDITOR': True,
}`  -> is not making any effect. Do I need to follow some convention?

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py` along with

```
 SWAGGER_SETTINGS =

      {            
       'JSON_EDITOR': True,        
      }
```

also added parsers in this particular order in `REST Framework setting`:

```
  'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
          'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
          'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
          'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
   )
```